# NSIS how to set a variable in messageBox on unistall section

Tags: nsis

i have a file when in this file there are differents LangString in differents languages.
In another file, in the unistall section, i want call into the messagebox, depending on the language, the correct LangString that is in the Langstring file.

In the install section it works fine

```
Section "Uninstall"

MessageBox MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION "$(UnSAVE_PROFILE)" IDYES borrar_perfil IDNO no_borrar_perfil
borrar_perfil:
    DeleteRegKey   HKCU "Software\XXX"
    RMDir /r "$APPDATA\mulehome\"
    RMDir /r "$APPDATA\..\Local\XXX\"
no_borrar_perfil:
  Delete "$INSTDIR\XXX"
```

LangString file:

```
LangString UnSAVE_PROFILE ${LANG_PORTUGUESE} "Do you want delete the configuration files?"
LangString UnSAVE_PROFILE ${LANG_SPANISH} "Quieres eliminar también los ficheros de configuración?"
```

Any idea?
Thx!!

Comment: Your question is not clear: What is the problem? The message always shows in english?

Answer (score 0):

If you propose a language selection in the installer with (in the `.onInit` function)

```
!insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY
```

you can get back that setting in the uninstaller (in the `un.onInit` function)

```
!insertmacro MUI_UNGETLANGUAGE
```

The language setting should be preserved by the installer in the registry, in my setups I precise the location for the persistence:

```
!define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_ROOT "HKCU"
!define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_KEY "Software\${Company}\${AppRegName}"
!define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_VALUENAME "Installer Language"
```

Also, don't forget to define separate LangStrings for the unsinstaller (as that application use different string tables) with `un.` prefix.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes i preserved like this form too in  un.onInit.
the problem is that the messageBox can't read the $(UnSAVE_PROFILE)    :S

Comment: I have no example in my own setups of message box with langstring during uninstaller, but I guess a problem with a missing `un.` prefix. Don't you have a warning in compiler output saying `Uninstaller language strings must start with un. (LangString name)!`?

Comment: Hi again Seki! i resolve my problem.... the problem was that the path of my langString was wrong :S
thanks for all :)